# Inferring type from a return automatically in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've got a method that I want to be able to pass in a parameter of one type (it will be a factory function) and get a different type back (the instantiated class). I'm struggling to get the return type correct, so I thought I'd step back and do it with simple `number` and `string` variables - but still can't get it to work in a generic way.

If I have a `convert` function that will convert numbers to strings and string to numbers:

```
let convert: Convert = function ( value ) {
    if ( typeof value === 'number' ) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    return parseInt( value.toString(), 10 );
}
```

Using this interface it works fine:

```
interface Convert {
    ( string ): number;
    ( number ): string;
}


let a = convert( '1' ); // a is a `number`
let b = convert( 2 );   // b is a `string`
```

If I don't use that interface, TypeScript sees the return automatically as `string | number`, which I can understand.

I tried using:

```
interface Convert {
    <Tout, Tin>(
        value: Tin
    ): Tout;
}
```

Thinking that it might mean `Tout` would be defined by the return value based on `Tin`, but no dice. To be honest, I don't really understand when generics are expected to be passed in and when they are there to be inferred by TypeScript.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here - should I just use a generic to tell TypeScript what I expect it to return, rather than expecting that it can do it automatically?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the compiler to inspect the implementation of the function and infer a generic function signature in which the type of the output is dependent on the type of the input, instead of the usual `(value: string | number) => string | number`.  I don't think the compiler is that clever, so you are going to be happiest if you explicitly type that function yourself (as you have with the `Convert` with overloads).

Comment: Another alternative is to create two functions `convertToString(val: any): string` and `convertToNumber(val: any): number`

Comment: @jcalz - Thanks. I sort of figured that. Could you post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.